# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'HttpExample'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

When running my Azure Functions App I'm getting the following error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'HttpExample'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind CosmosDB to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient'.
```

This is my Run() function in Function1.cs file:

```
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "policy")] HttpRequest req,
        [CosmosDB(Connection = "CosmosConnectionString")] DocumentClient cosmos,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        
        var query = "SELECT * FROM Policy";
        
        var policies = GetDocumentsByQuery(
           cosmos,
           "AR",
           "Policy",
           query).ToList();

        return new OkObjectResult(policies);
    }
```

I pass my CosmosConnectionString as a user secret. I'm using Azure Functions v4 with CosmosDB v4 preview and .NET Core 6. I am out of ideas why I'm getting this error. I worked previously with .NET Core 3.1 and earlier version of Azure functions + CosmosDB and it worked fine.

EDIT:

```
public static IQueryable<dynamic> GetDocumentsByQuery(DocumentClient cosmos, string database, string collection, string query, string partitionKey = null)
    {
        try
        {
            FeedOptions feedOptions;
            if (partitionKey == null)
            {
                feedOptions = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, PopulateQueryMetrics = true };
            }
            else
            {
                feedOptions = new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey), PopulateQueryMetrics = true };
            }

            var documentQuery =
            cosmos.CreateDocumentQuery(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(database, collection),
                query,
                feedOptions);

            return documentQuery;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're binding against the wrong type:

`Can't bind CosmosDB to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient'`

For 4.x, use `CosmosClient`. Taken from [HTTP trigger, get multiple docs, using CosmosClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=csharp#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-cosmosclient)

> The following example shows a C# function that retrieves a list of documents. The function is triggered by an HTTP request. The code uses a `CosmosClient` instance provided by the Azure Cosmos DB binding, available in [extension version 4.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#cosmos-db-extension-4x-and-higher), to read a list of documents. The `CosmosClient` instance could also be used for write operations.

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CosmosDBSamplesV2
{
    public static class DocsByUsingCosmosClient
    {  
        [FunctionName("DocsByUsingCosmosClient")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post",
                Route = null)]HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "ToDoItems",
                containerName: "Items",
                Connection = "CosmosDBConnection")] CosmosClient client,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var searchterm = req.Query["searchterm"].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchterm))
            {
                return (ActionResult)new NotFoundResult();
            }

            Container container = client.GetDatabase("ToDoItems").GetContainer("Items");

            log.LogInformation($"Searching for: {searchterm}");

            QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(
                "SELECT * FROM items i WHERE CONTAINS(i.Description, @searchterm)")
                .WithParameter("@searchterm", searchterm);
            using (FeedIterator<ToDoItem> resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<ToDoItem>(queryDefinition))
            {
                while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    FeedResponse<ToDoItem> response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
                    ToDoItem item = response.First();
                    log.LogInformation(item.Description);
                }
            }

            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if method name starts with "I", console shows this error. I can not understand why but when I change my method name (and file name) it works. I do not know which one is required.

My old code was:

```
[FunctionName("IPAddressblabla")] //<-- Problematic "I" charachter in IPAdd...
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function...
```

my new code looks like:

```
[FunctionName("iPAddressblabla")]//<-- make "I" to lowercase.(i)
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function...
```

I also found this Github issue. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4648